# I want ggplot gridline thickness to be different for major/minor gridlines

Tags: r, ggplot2

[My example is taken from here (link).](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-barplots-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization) R version is 3.4.3, ggplot2 version is 2.2.1

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(dose=c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),
                    len=c(4.2, 10, 29.5))

    ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dose, y=len)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Almost every ggplot2 tutorial shows some simple graph. I always notice the *major gridlines* are about twice the thickness of the *minor gridlines*, which is what I'd expect. This is shown in the first image below. It looks great.

Whenever **I** plot something on ggplot the minor and major gridlines share the same weight, the same thickness, **by default**. Why? I didn't change any gridline settings? Is there some R Studio global setting I accidentaly enabled/disabled? I want the minor gridlines to be a lighter weight than the major gridlines, like the first image shown. The second image is what I get when I ggplot the graph.

[image: correct_grid.png]

[image: incorrect_grid.png]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can change the weight of the grid lines by using the theme function

```
df <- data.frame(dose=c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),
            len=c(4.2, 10, 29.5))

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dose, y=len)) +
       geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
       theme(panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.5), panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 1))
```

Comment: Thanks for that information. But **why doesn't this behavior happen by default**, like it does in every reproducible example I see of ggplot on the web? Maybe my ggplot2 is newer and this behavior has changed in newer versions of ggplot2.

Comment: This behavior does happen by default for me with both `theme_grey()` and `theme_bw()`. I'm using ggplot2 2.2.1.9000. The major gridlines are  indeed twice the thickness of the minor gridlines. If you set `theme_grey()` (`theme_set(theme_grey())`) and then do `theme_get()$panel.grid.minor` you'll see a `size` row that is set to `rel` 0.5, meaning half size relative to the default line width (which is found in `theme_get()$line`.

Comment: I never changed any `theme_set` settings. Weird. Why would my `size` be set to `num 0.25`? Is there any way to reset all ggplot2 settings *back to default*? `> theme_get()$panel.grid.minor
List of 6
 $ colour       : chr "white"
 $ size         : num 0.25
 $ linetype     : NULL
 $ lineend      : NULL
 $ arrow        : logi FALSE
 $ inherit.blank: logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "element_line" "element"`